# Why would a mask mandate be needed if masks are extremely popular

Tags: united-states, covid-19

Massachusetts Governor Baker says that he doesn't want to institute a state-wide mandate for masks in schools, he's leaving the decision up to individual municipalities.

A recent [MassINC poll](https://www.massincpolling.com/the-topline/new-poll-81-of-mass-voters-support-school-mask-mandate) found that 81% of registered voters support a state-wide mandate. But if so many people are in favor of masking, why would we need a mandate? Isn't it reasonable to assume that anyone in favor of the mandate would also wear masks voluntarily, and make their children do so?

When asked why he's not mandating masks, he responded:

> We made a strong recommendation on this, and as I said, I believe the vast majority, if not all, school districts are going to adopt that recommendation, which I think is a good thing.

Yet many people still seem to be criticizing Baker for his approach. If virtually all unvaccinated students will be masked under the current approach, what's the problem? This is far different from the states where the governor is actively *prohibiting* local mandates.

Comment: Because it's weak and doesn't allow localities asking people to follow the recommendation any way to back it up if someone/some group refuses.

Comment: Because 19% still don't. Why should we mandate sober driving if 81% of people were going to drive sober anyway?

Comment: @Jontia The localties aren't "asking", they're mandating. They have local police departments who can back it up.

Comment: @user253751 Being against mask mandates is not the same as being against masks. And being against a statewide mandate is not the same as being against local mandates.

Comment: Just because masks are popular doesn't mean everyone is wearing them

Answer (score 8):

There are a couple of key reasons.

1. Just because 81% of the population supports a mask mandate doesn't mean 81% of the population is wearing masks
2. The 19% of the population that doesn't support it is unlikely to be wearing masks

There are already cases where students are attending school with a positive covid test. In those cases wearing a mask could help limit the impact those students have on their peers. And in these cases it is unlikely that they would be wearing a mask which is something a mask mandate would prevent.

https://thehill.com/homenews/state-watch/567701-80-students-potentially-exposed-to-coronavirus-after-child-attends

> Eighty students from a school in Reno, Nev., could have been exposed to the coronavirus after a fellow student who received a positive test attended school two days later, according to CNN.

Comment: 1. Being against a mandate doesn't mean you're against masking, it often means you're against government overreach. Or you think it should be a local decision, not statewide.

Comment: 2. All the local school districts are expected to mandate masks.

Comment: 3. The article you linked to says that Nevada has a statewide mask mandate in schools. So the mandate didn't prevent the infections.

Comment: @Barmar You are missing the points 1) being for a mask mandate doesn't mean you are wearing a mask 2) Just because the schools enforce it doesn't mean that it can't spread in other places that don't have requirements 3) Again, you missed the critical point which is that people are going out in public when they know they are infected which means masks are critical for preventing it 4) in the end this is a form of protection that is really no different than a law requiring you to wear a seatbelt or wear a helmet on a bike and is for everyone's protection.

Comment: We're only talking about a mask mandate in schools, not all public places.

Comment: @Barmar My answer would still apply no matter where the mandate was for. My point was and still is that just because people are supporting a mask mandate doesn't mean they are wearing masks and we have people who have tested positive for coivd going out in public which is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @Barmar All it takes is a small percentage of people not wearing masks for covid to start spreading throughout the entire school.

Comment: My point is that you keep bringing up things that wouldn't be addressed by the mandate in the first place. The poll was about masks in schools, so what people do in other public places is irrelevant. And if someone were in favor of mask mandates in schools, and they went to a school that had a "Masks required" sign on the door, would they really disobey it just because there's no statewide mandate? I didn't see anyone objecting when I went to the Apple Store and they asked us to mask up.

Comment: @Barmar How can you address the fact that people supporting a mask mandate doesn't mean people would actually wear masks? And yes people are disobeying requests to wear masks. What is the difference between wearing a mask because a local school tells you and the state tells you?

Comment: @Barmar It sounds like you disagree with my logic and that isn't a reason to badger me with comments complaining about my answer.

Comment: Maybe. Note that the mask mandate in question is only for unvaccinated people. 65% of MA residents are fully vaccinated.

Comment: I guess we're both making assumptions. I assumed that people in favor of a mask mandate will voluntarily wear masks when in a location that requests it, you assume they won't unless it comes from a higher authority.

Comment: @Barmar The mandate is only for unvaccinated people? That is critical information that should have been in your question as it would change my answer. When you are asking a question you should include as much relevant information as possible such as the mask mandate not being required for vaccinated people. My understanding and answer to this question was it was for everyone not just the unvaccinated. And from what I have seen it is the unvaccinated that are most likely not going to want to wear a mask in the first place.

Comment: Actually, I'm confusing things. The poll just said "Require masks for all people to enter school buildings in Massachusetts". But the state recommendation, and what's actually being implemented by most localities, is mask mandates for unvaccinated people to enter schools.

Comment: @JoeW "What is the difference between wearing a mask because a local school tells you and the state tells you?"  The average voter has much more influence over local decisions than state decisions.  There is more legitimacy behind a decision made locally than one made statewide.

Comment: I'm not against wearing masks, but why is the consensus opinion that we have to force others? People might have reasons not to wear them that we're not even capable of understanding.

Comment: @elvis because it has been showed evidence of helping to stop the spread of COVID-19

Comment: @JoeW I'm not sure... it seems obvious to us but who says that we are smarter than them. I think all we can do is educate and bring facts, but forcing others seems to conflict with what a free country should be like.

Comment: @elvis I mean we also require people to wear seatbelts, helmets and do other things for public safety.  Just because this is a free country doesn't mean you won't be required to do some things for the safety of everyone else.

Comment: @JoeW Helmets are for your safety, not everyone else's.

Comment: @user76284 Helmet laws are not just about personal safety but but the impact that an injury/death can have on others. A head injury can lead to massive medical bills and the loss of ability to help provide for others as an example.

Comment: @JoeW That's not "the safety of everyone else".

Comment: @user76284 Well I am not the only one who classifies them as as part of public safety laws.